# Custom microprocessor getting hot

Tags: microprocessor, testing, short-circuit

We're working on using an embedded microprocessor on a custom board. We've gone through a couple of prototype boards and finally have come to a design that our team was satisfied. We've tested about 30 of these boards and have been satisfied. As always, we always test all voltage test points for shorts and measure their values when the device is turned on to assure all test points are operating at their correct voltage value.

We recently received a new batch of boards of the same revision and noticed that the TI microprocessor part was heating up very quickly. The issue came up when we were installing the Linux OS and a warning came up that the microprocessor was over 100C on the debug shell.

Before powering on the device, we went through our resistance and visual checks to assure no shorts. None of the voltage rails to the MPU showed a difference in resistance compared to the working boards. All voltage rails from the PMIC to the MPU were at their correct operating voltage value. Visual inspection didn't show any shorts or bridges on the peripherals to the uP. We've seen this issue on the first three boards from this batch.

I'm not sure where the assembly house received thid batch of microprocessors, since I wasn't heavily involved in that process. Due to the chip shortages we are seeing, I wouldn't be surprised if they had to go to an unauthorized vendor to acquire the chips. Is there a chance that these chips might be fakes/duds? Would it be worth getting an X-ray on the part to see if there are any shorts on one of the pins?

Comment: I had a bad crystal in such a context, just overclocking the system. It's worth a check

Comment: Have you checked un-unsed I/O pins for **floating?** Floating input pins can cause excess supply current and overheating. When you put a probe on such a pin, it may show a valid low logic level, because the probing instrument pulls it down.

Comment: Such floating pins might be detectable (oscillating in the MHz range) with an oscilloscope and 100x probe.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a late night. While probing with the scope also monitor the current, if you hit an oscillating point it may stop and not show on the scope but the current may drop. Also check your power supply to be sure it is solid. Possibly a erroneous part got installed. Also validate your heat sinking system to be sure it is working properly. Be sure no other parts are getting hot, if so they may be causing your problem. Be sure ground is ground on all the interconnected systems.